# USB-C assistance

Tags: power, pcb-design, usb-c, usb-pd

I am creating a phased-array controller of sorts and will be using USB-C to power the controller. I have not used USB-C on my own PCBs. I would like a bit of clarification.

I used the generic USB-C bus from KiCad's library, and was instructed to use the full one after I had shown this schematic to my professor with the symbol for USB-C power only.

Anyway, what is the best way to deal with the remaining pins? They will go unused, so would it be best to just leave them floating? Or should I ground them?

[image: KiCAD Schematic]

Comment: Your problem should be not the unconnected pins, but how much power do you need from Type-C provider. If it is under 500mA, then it is ok, but if you need more, then your circuit needs some means to sense the voltage on CC pins.

Comment: You should connect all the VBUS pins together and all the GND pins together.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving them unused is fine as long as the CC pins are there it will detect power and turn on VBUS.